# Maximum possible number of 1012-element subsets of {1,2,...,2024} such that no three intersect at more than one element

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

I came across the following problem:

> At most how many $1012$-element subsets of $\lbrace 1,2,\dots,2024 \rbrace$ may be chosen such that the intersection of any three subsets has at most one element?

I tried small cases. For example, I considered $3$-element subsets of $\lbrace 1,2,3,4,5,6 \rbrace$. By playing around (see table below), I think I got that for this case, the maximum is 8 subsets:

| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x | x | x |  |  |  |
|  |  |  | x | x | x |
| x | x |  | x |  |  |
|  | x | x |  | x |  |
|  |  | x |  | x | x |
| x |  |  | x | x |  |
| x |  | x |  |  | x |
|  | x |  | x |  | x |

Essentially, we reach the point that for all triples $(a,b,c)$ at least one of $a-b, b-c, a-c$ are already in two subsets together. However, I have no idea how to prove that this is the maximum amount for even the $\lbrace 1,2,3,4,5,6 \rbrace$ case, and am stumped on how to proceed with the general or $2024$ case.

Intuitively, I feel as though there must be some way to upper-bound the number of subsets and then give a construction that satisfies that upper bound, but I am lost on how to proceed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: @CalvinLin If there are $9$ $3$-element subsets, then that gives $27$ total elements, allowing for repetition. If each element appeared in at most $4$ subsets, that would give $4 \cdot 6 = 24$, a contradiction. So yes, there is an element in at least $5$ sets. However, why is that a contradiction? I'm not sure I see why an element being in $5$ subsets means that the condition fails

Comment: What else can we say? How else can we proceed? $\quad$ Are you familiar with Incidence matrix?

Comment: Yes I am familiar with incidence matrices — that entry $(i,j)$ is $1$ if and only if $i$ and $j$ are in a set together? Or a different kind of incidence matrix?

Comment: Well, we'd like to say that some element is in $3$ of those $5$ sets to get a contradiction.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. For example, if we said WLOG that $1$ was the element that was in $5$ sets, we could have: $(1,2,3), (1,4,6), (1,4,5), (1,2,5), (1,3,6)$. This is the limit case, because each other number occurs exactly twice. If we had just one more set, we could get a contradiction...

Comment: Great! So you have proof for the n =6 case, though it doesn't seem like it would easily generalize. Can you add that into the problem statement?

Comment: Thanks! So the argument is as follows? If one element occurs in $5$ sets, we can have at most $5$ sets; if each element occurs in at most $4$ sets, we can have at most $8$ sets, because we would have $4 \cdot 6 = 24$ elements with repeat, and since each set has $3$ elements, this yields $24/3 = 8$ sets. The maximum of $5$ and $8$ is $8$, so it follows that the answer for the $n=6$ case is $8$.

Comment: Yes (with details filled in). $\quad$ FWIW That was the "hard" case. For large $n$, it's very hard to construct these sets. EG If you have 1 such set, the 2nd set is heavily constrained. We might have a 3rd set, but a 4th set seems dubious. Try it with like $n = 100$.

Comment: Wait, actually I'm not sure I follow. For example, we could have:

$(1,2,3), (1,4,6), (1,4,5), (1,2,5), (1,3,6)$ and then we could add $(3,4,6)$. So that would give $6$ sets. What am I missing?

Comment: Oh, I was basing my comments mostly on what you were saying, and just doing a quick gut check. $\quad$ I had a different approach, but turns out to be wrong. I can find 10 subsets.

Comment: Interestingly, this is a scenario where the small $n$ case doesn't help with the big $n$ case. I've written up why in my solution. $\quad$ And that also explains why I was so confused when talking through this, because I kept on switching notation in my head.

Comment: Hmm, but so if the maximum is 10, that heuristically aligns with an argument that shows that no element can occur in a set 6 times. Indeed, if an element occurred 6 times, the above argument would suffice. So, each element occurs at most 5 times, which means there are at most $(6 \cdot 5)/3 = 10$ sets, as you claim. Could this generalize?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146414/discussion-between-vietajumping-and-calvin-lin).

Comment: NICE argument for $n = 6$! I'm excited that you thought through this can came up with a shorter proof! $\quad$   "Knowing" that the answer for large $n$ is 4, that indicates that your argument for small $n$ cannot generalize to large $n$. (I'd be surprised if there's an argument that works for small and large $n$.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a given $n$, we want to find $n-$element subsets out of $[2n]$, such that the intersection of any 3 subsets is at most 1 element.

First, find 4 subsets such that the intersection of any 3 has $\leq 1$ elements in common.

> Let $ A \cup B \cup C \cup D  = [2n]$ with $|A| = |B| = \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor$ and $|C| = |D| = \lceil \frac{n}{2} \rceil$ be any partition of the appropriate size.
>  Take the 4 subsets: $A \cup C, A \cup D, B \cup C, B \cup D$.
>  Clearly the intersection of any 3 subsets is the emptyset.

Now, let's show that the maximum is indeed 4 for large $n$.
Suppose we have $k$ subsets that fulfills the condition.
Set up the standard incidence matrix, where the rows are the subsets and the columns are the elements.

Let's count column triples $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$.

Consider a column. Let there be $c_i$ 1's in it. We have $ \sum c_i = kn$ as the sum of the matrix.
The column contributes ${c_i \choose 3 }$ column-triples, so the total is $ \sum { c_i \choose 3}$.
By Jensen's inequality, we get $\sum { c_i \choose 3 } \geq 2n { \frac{ \sum c_i } { 2n } \choose 3 } = 2n { \frac{k}{2} \choose 3 }$.

Consider any 3 rows.
Since any 3 sets have an intersection of at most 1, these 3 rows can yield at most 1 column triple. Thus, there are at most ${k \choose 3 } $ triples.

Hence, $ 2n { \frac{k}{2} \choose 3 } \leq \text{ total column triples} \leq { k \choose 3 }$, or that $2n \leq \frac{ 8(k-1) } { (k-4) }$.
For $k = 5$, the RHS is $\frac{ 8 \times 5}{1} > 2 \times 1012$.
Thus, we have $k \leq 4$.

Thus, the maximum for $n \geq 21$ is 4.

---

BONUS

Note that for $n=3$, this argument doesn't work because we always have $6 \leq 8 \frac{ k-1}{k-4}$ for $k > 4$, and so we don't have a bound on $k$. Instead, we approach it in another manner, and count row pairs $(1, 1)$.

Each row has $n$ 1's, so there are ${n \choose 2}$ pairs. Since there are $k$ rows, so there are $ k { n \choose 2 } $ pairs.

Consider any 2 columns. Since any 3 sets have an intersection of at most 1, these 2 columns can yield at most 2 pairs of $(1, 1)$. Since there are ${2n \choose 2 }$ pairs of columns, thus there are at most $ 2 { 2n \choose 2 }$ such pairs.

Hence,  $k { n \choose 2 } =  \text{total pairs} \leq 2 {2n \choose 2 }$, or that $k \leq \frac{ 4(2n-1) } { n-1 } $.

Note that this is just an upper bound. It need not be achieved (hence may not be the maximum).

For $n =3$, we have $k \leq \frac{ 4 \times 5 } { 2 } = 10$.
I leave it to you to construct these 10 such subsets. Pursue your logic in the comments and build out from there. You can also use the fact that we have equality to make further deductions about the structure.

> The equality conditions are:
>  Every element appears in exactly 3 subsets.
>  Every pair of elements appear in exactly 2 subsets.

> $\{ 1, 2, 3\}, \{1, 3, 4 \}, \{1, 4, 5 \}, \{1, 5, 6 \}, \{1, 6, 2 \}, \{2, 3, 5 \} , \{ 3, 4, 6 \}, \{4, 5, 2 \}, \{ 5, 6 , 3 \}, \{ 6, 2, 4 \}$.

---

Notes

- In the comments, OP eventually came up with a much simpler argument for $n=6$.

  - If there are $\geq 11$ subsets, then one element (say $z$) must appear in at least $\lceil \frac{ 11\times 3}{6} \rceil = 6$ sets.
  - Consider the $6\times 2$ non-$z$ elements in these 6 sets. One element (say $y$) must appear in at least $\lceil \frac{12}{5} \rceil = 3$ sets. Then, the intersection of these 3 sets contains $ \{y, z \}$, which is a contradiction.
  - Note that this argument requires "knowing" that the answer is 10.
- What happens for $n = 4, 5, \ldots 20$? I'd love for you to investigate that.
- Small technicality/issue that is standard to deal with in such incidence matrix questions. Technically ${ x \choose 3 } = \frac{ x (x-1)(x-2) } {6}$ isn't convex in the $[0, 2]$ region, so we can't immediately Jensens it. Instead, what we actually use is the obviously convex function defined as

$${ x \choose 3 } = \begin{cases}  0 & x \leq 2  \\
 \frac{x(x-1)(x-2) } { 6} & x > 2 \end{cases} $$

Comment: Wow, so this actually turns out to be quite complicated. Thank you for this!

Comment: @vietajumping It's a "standard" incidence matrix argument, though that assumes familiarity with the concept.

Comment: Is it correct that the "simplest" way to describe the four sets for large $n$ is just as the lower half, the upper half, the odd elements, and the even elements?

Comment: A simple argument for $2n=6$, without knowing the solution is $10$: There are $\binom{6}{3}=20$ possible $3$-element subsets. Each of the $15$ unique pairs $\{a,b\}$ appears in $4$ of those subsets, for a total of $60$ times. Each is only allowed to be in two of the subsets in the solution, a total of $30$ times. Each subset contains three pairs, so removing $10$ subsets by careful choice will remove each pair twice as $(10)(3)=(15)(2)$. I don't think this extends to $2n=8$ but it might.